# Why the the newline \n doesn't work with printf() in PHP

Tags: php

IGNORE THIS QUESTION. ASKED IN ERROR:

What's the difference between the following 2 printf statements:

```
printf($variable, "\n");

printf("Hello\n");
```

The newline gets ignored in the 1st printf() statement. But it works fine with the 2nd statement.

The only way I can use the new line is by splitting the 1st statement in to 2 separate statements:

```
printf($variable);
printf("\n");
```

This sounds like a query from an absolute novice however I feel the newline was supported pretty good in Java but not in PHP.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\n` in Java either. Please read the Java documentation. With Java you should use `%n` instead. But regardless, your question is mistagged since it is most definitely not about Java.

Comment: Please don't use random tags. This is a PHP question.

Comment: Sure. This was asked in error. Need to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\n` is being ignored because as stated in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) first parameter is `format` which should be printed and rest of parameters are values which this format can use, for instance:

```
$num = 2.12; 
printf("formatted value = %.1f", $num);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^
//             |                  |
//             format             |
// value which can be put in format in place of `%X` where `X` represents type
```

will print `formatted value = 2.1` because in format `%.1f` you decided to print only one digit after dot in floating point number.

To make format use string argument you need to use `%s` placeholder like in case of `print("hello %s world","beautiful")` which would put `beautiful` in place of `%s` and print `hello beautiful world`.

Now lets back to your code. In `printf($variable, "\n");` `$variable` represents format, and it most probably doesn't have `any %s` for string  in it which would let you put use `"\n"` argument in this format. This means that `"\n"` will be ignored (not used in format) so will not be printed.

Code like this

```
printf("Hello\n");
```

or

```
printf($variable);
printf("\n");
```

doesn't have this problem because it explicitly use `\n` in format which should be printed.

So it seems that you may either want to use

```
printf("%s\n", $value)
```

which seems like overkill because you can simply concatenate strings using `.` operator and print them like

```
print($value."\n")
```

or

```
echo $value."\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

### Java != PHP

As it is written in [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

> There are two string operators. The first is the concatenation
>   operator ('`.`'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left
>   arguments.

The correct syntax in PHP is:

```
printf($variable . "\n");
```

Comment: whoa. mind blown. java isn't the same as php... I had no clue.

Comment: If you're using `printf` this way (i.e. without a format) then you might as well use `print`.

Answer (score 3):

Do it from \r\n instead of \n

like this

```
<?php
print("myname is \r\n sumit");
?>`
```

The Output Look Like...

My name is
sumit

Answer (score 2):

You're using `printf()` incorrectly. You need to use `%s` to represent where the newline character will be placed:

```
printf($variable . "%s", "\n");
```

Comment: This seems quite a bizarre way of using `printf`!  You're meant to use it to format variables as @Pshemo says above: it's `printf(format,value[,value[...]]);` so using it to format a static string doesn't really make sense.  If you really want to use it that way, you ought to have `printf('%s%s',$variable,"\n");`.